# dynamically change the model - Database First

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My DB is MS-SQL with EF 6.0 using Data-First approach.
I'm syncing with hundreds of databases (tables scheme is **almost** the same on all of them), dynamically changing the connection string when required.

My issue is that some databases have a slightly different scheme than others.
on all of them I have a table X which has a column Y and Y can be either a bit, or a byte.

[image: sql tables shown]

EF generated a model class, based on the database which has column Y **defined as byte.** So when querying, it obviously throws an exception.

> The 'Y' property on table 'X' could not be set to a
>   System.Boolean value. you must set the value to System.Byte.

[image: exception image]

Is there a way, dynamically change the model, in Database-First approach, to resolve this issue ? or perhaps cast returned value, to a byte, before its assigned to the model ? to prevent the exception ?

Comment: Database wise you are only left with one option. update the schema. Query wise you can dynamically build the expression based on the type of the property/column of the model.

Comment: Simple idea: can you model it as object or create a own class which can handle bit and byte input?Think of the existing possiblity to assign i.,e. a double to a int with a implicit cast.

Comment: @GertArnold after 5 days, any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to get this done in database-first. In short: create two sets of mapping and model files and choose one set in the config file.

### Model files

When an EDMX is created, EF creates three files:

- The store model (*.ssdl).
- The class (or conceptual) model (*.csdl).
- The mapping between these two models (*.msl).

These file are embedded as resource files in the compiled assembly and normally you don't need to be aware of their existence. At runtime, EF will load the files from the assembly, directed by the resource paths in the config file's connection string, usually looking like...

```xml
metadata=res://*/...
```

It is possible to embed another set of resource files into the assembly and modify the connection string accordingly, but it takes a couple of steps to achieve this.

For brevity, I will refer to "mapping and model files" as "model files".

### Adding two sets of model files

#### Step 1 - Create the first set

Creating the first set of files is nothing but creating an EDMX. I used a very simple database table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Person] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Person] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Person_IsActive]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsActive]
```

In a simple C# console application I created an EDMX off this table.

#### Step 2 - Add partial files

In my case only a `Person` class was created:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In EF, the property `IsActive` must be mapped to a `bit` database field, so it's not possible to simply map it to to `byte` (or `tinyint`) field, as you already found out. we have to add a second property to support the byte field:

```
partial class Person
{
    public byte IsActiveByte { get; set; }
}
```

The main challenge is how to get either of these two properties mapped to the one field in the database depending on its data type.

#### Step 3 - Copy and modify the second set

Now the model files of the first set are embedded in the assembly. We want to make them available as regular files in order to copy and modify them. This can be done by temporarily changing the setting "Metadata Artifact Processing" from its default (Embed in Output Assembly) to **Copy to Output Directory**. Now build the project and find the three files in the bin/Debug folder.

Restore the "Metadata Artifact Processing" setting to its default, move the files to the project's root directory and copy them into a second set. I ended up having these files, of which the "BitModel" ones are the originals:

```
BitModel.csdl
BitModel.msl
BitModel.ssdl
ByteModel.csdl
ByteModel.msl
ByteModel.ssdl
```

For the ByteModel files to support the `Person.IsActiveByte` property I made these changes (original line/edited line):

- csdl:

  ```
  <Property Name="IsActive" Type="Boolean" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="IsActiveByte" Type="Byte" Nullable="false" />
  ```
- ssdl:

  ```
  <Property Name="IsActive" Type="bit" Nullable="false" />
  <Property Name="IsActive" Type="tinyint" Nullable="false" />
  ```
- msl:

  ```
  <ScalarProperty Name="IsActive" ColumnName="IsActive" />
  <ScalarProperty Name="IsActiveByte" ColumnName="IsActive" />
  ```

The BitModel files can now be deleted.

#### Step 4 - Embed the second set as resource

The next step is to add the ByteModel files to the project and in their properties set "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource". Rebuild the project.

The files are embedded slightly differently than the way EF does it originally. Inspecting the .exe file in a disassembler shows that their resource names are `<namespace>.<filename>`, in my case: `BitOrBye.ByteModel.csdl`, etc.

#### Step 5 - Add a connection string

EF added a connection string to the project looking like...

```xml
<add name="DbBitContext" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/BitModel.csdl
                              |res://*/BitModel.ssdl
                              |res://*/BitModel.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\sql2016;initial catalog=DbBit;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I copied this connection string and commented out the original one. In the copied connection string I modified the resource paths:

```xml
<add name="DbBitContext" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/BitOrByte.ByteModel.csdl
                              |res://*/BitOrByte.ByteModel.ssdl
                              |res://*/BitOrByte.ByteModel.msl;
    ... />
```

Now the assembly is ready to connect to a database in which the `Person.IsActive` field is a `tinyint`. The property `Person.IsActive` is not a mapped property any more, `Person.IsActiveByte` is.

Enter the previous connection string and the context maps to the `bit` field, so the connection string can now be used to determine which type of database is supported, "BitModel" or "ByteModel".

### Limitations

In LINQ-to-Entities queries only mapped properties can be addressed. For example, a query like...

```
context.People.Where(p => p.Id > 10).Select(p => p.Name).ToList()
```

...is OK. But when the "BitModel" is active, a query like...

```
context.People.Where(p => p.IsActiveByte == 1).Select(p => p.Name).ToList()
```

...will throw the infamous *The specified type member 'IsActiveByte' is not supported in LINQ to Entities* exception.

Of course you already have this restriction. You probably want to add unmapped properties to your classes that channel the value of both the bye and bit properties to one property you'll use in the application code.

A possible way out is to use [EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters)
. This little gem enables you to define global filters in a context that can be turned on and off. Thus, two global filter can be defined...

```
modelBuilder.Filter("IsActiveBit", (Person p) => p.IsActive, true);
modelBuilder.Filter("IsActiveByte", (Person p) => p.IsActiveByte, 1);
```

...of which you will add one, depending on the type of database you connect to, which can be inferred from the connection string.

Comment: thank you. if I understand correctly, this requires me to know in advance, that a database's column needs to be read as byte or as a bit.

Comment: Yes, that is, you need to know this before the first context is created and used. For performance reasons, EF stores the model + mapping into the app domain once. So you could write code that reads the appropriate meta data from the database by regular ADO.Net at runtime and then decide which entity connection string you'll offer the new contexts.

Comment: so as I understand it,  It's somehow  similar to creating two different EDMX "mapping" files. so if already, as Colin here suggested, why not create two EDMX files, two dbContexts, - I guess I could use ADO.net to read the meta data and decide which dbContext to use. would it not be less complicated to maintain in the future ? regardless, your answer is very informative +1

Comment: I think it will be hard to have two EDMXs in one assembly that use the same set of entity classes. Each EDMX will want to create its own set of classes, so you'll get conflicts (even when the classes are in different namespaces).

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that a database-first context always reads its model and mapping metadata from these embedded resource files. If you want a context to have a different model, either another EDMX is required, or another set of model files. Subtyping isn't an option. Of course, as said, with code-first this is all much easier.

Comment: For the record, I briefly tried your option *why not create two EDMX files*? It is possible to have two edmx files that map to the same `Person` class, but the last EDMX that is saved modifies the class according to its own configuration. You *can* add a partial file containing the IsActiveByte property and always, ALWAYS, save the "BitContext" last, but I think that's very error prone.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanna give you some options to consider :

**OPTION 1 :**

Adjust the schema in the database's side, if possible, because it will only give you a headache in the long run.

**OPTION 2 :**

Or switch to code-first to make room for some tweaks. Furthermore, if you rely on EDMX, this feature has been dropped in EF Core, anyway.

**OPTION 3 :**

Give that table a special treatment, like, exclude it from your main Context, and make a new context just to take care of it.

Most likely, other than that, as far as I know, it will never work.

Sorry I can only give you some ideas.

Comment: these are indeed my options. hopefully there's a bypass I am yet aware of.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is not a db-first attempt. It's a sort of "code-first-wtih-generated-classes-from-db" attempt.

1. Generate master-schema
2. Generate code form master
3. Connect to different dbs with generated code

What you did wrong is using the wrong master-schema. You tried to access with the wrong datatypes.
Write a schama (or code directly) with compatible datatypes. Easiest way is to use string-only-properties and map them later.

#### Example-Class

```
[Table("dbo.G")]
public class G
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Column("CI_BlockWithID")]
    public string CiBlockWithIdStr { get; set; }
    public int CiBlockWithId
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(this.CiBlockWithIdStr); }
        set { this.CiBlockWithIdStr = value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

The example shows a code-first snippet to explain the mechanics. You need code with compatible datatypes - string in this example.

The question is how do you get this code?

a. Code-First (which you don't want to do)

b. Force the code-generator to chosse other datatypes (generate from master schema).

Please be aware that strong types are better than using string. This should only show you the mechanic. If you're reading a TinyInt and a Byte, you could try to use Int32 as master-type and so on (Depending on db-provider).
In MySQL we use very much strings to read DateTimes and Enums.

Comment: so basically what you're suggesting is to convert everything to `code-first` (defining fields as varchar in the database is redundant, once I got custom getter and setter I can do whatever I want, in db-first, I can't override them)

Comment: The basic suggestion is that you create one schema without data. This will be you master-schema. You adjust the datatypes in this schema and use it as base for your "db-first"-approch. The example-code shows the code-first attempt which should explain why you need a master schema with compatible-datatypes.

Comment: in data-first you can not override the getter and setter of the model classes. at best, you can extend the class because its partial. If my master scheme will have `CI_BlockWithID` defined as `varchar`, it will get the same exception. no implicit cast will be done. this won't get me further

Comment: I'm not an expert in model-first but in code-first it is working, because every data can be read as string. Did you try with `varchar`? Your error is a cast-problem between byte and boolean which aren't compatible.

Comment: in code first you can do custom setter and getter on your class. in data-base first however you can't. and fortunately, entity framework, will never try to do implicit casts from string to.. well. anything that is not a string - nonetheless - thank you.

Comment: I think we're talking about two different things. I speak about having a string/varchar column. If you want to use it in a different type, you can inherit you generated class. Did you try to read you column as string/varchar?

Comment: for the fun of it, as expected, `property on 'CiBlockWithId' could not be set to a 'System.Boolean' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.String'. '` - changed database's column to varchar. then updated model from database and at last changed database column to `bit`, and tried to query.

Answer (score 1):

1. Could you add a view to all the databases that does the conversion from bit to byte within its defining sql? Then include the view instead of the table. You may also have to use stored procedures to do updates and inserts. Effectively you'd be using the view to make the databases *appear* identical to a single  `DbContext`.
2. Could you have multiple `DbContext`s that inherit from a base context, then dynamically change the context when required, instead of changing connection strings? I use a Unit of Work / Repository pattern with dependency injection. My Unit of Work is dependent on a `DbContext`:

   ```
   public class UnitOfWork 
   {
       private readonly DbContext context;

       public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
       {
           this.context = context;
       }
   }
   ```

And I define what should be injected into the unit of work during application startup. If you used this pattern you would inject the correct `DbContext` at the point that you are currently switching connection strings.

Comment: I guess (2) will probably work, although maintaining two EDMX files only to allow some flexibility on the model setter for one single column, on one single table, feels like killing a mosquito with an A-1 tank.  it amazes me this is such a big headache for what sounds to me like a not so far-fetched scenario. dare I say a potentially common one when dealing with legacy databases.

Comment: I realise that I have talked about inheritance here. And that is a relatively easy option using code first. It strikes me that ditching database-first, as others have suggested, would reduce the headache enormously.

Comment: Breaking up your contexts can have other advantages. I think 2 seems like a solid approach. The Unit Of Work pattern is irrelevant to this question though. It is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a partial class for your entity and add a property which can handle any situation:

```
public partial class X
{
    public int TrueY
    {
        //add verification logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Any situation? What do you mean? EF is very strict in which CLR datatype can be mapped to which store datatype.

Comment: @GertArnold, I meant that if you don't know what exactly type of prop you can add additional prop in partial class where you can for instance try int.TryParse(MyProp)

Comment: The issue is: how to map a database field that can either be int or bit to *one* property in the class model. I.e. the mapping of what you call "MyProp" is the problem.

Comment: Yep, I've just re-read the question and you are right in the Model-first approach it is possible if you change this prop ,for instance, to type `string` and only then work with this using partial class approach or something else.

Comment: That's too vague. Try to turn your answer into a working example.

Comment: @Max the problem is before that. when EF tries to populate the model with values, it throws an exception. you can't add a non mapped property and expect it to rely on a value that you never get. if you ignore the value, in your model, you won't get it, if you don't ignore it, you get an exception, if you hack your way trying to act smart and set its type as `dynamic` or `object` EF throws `the result does not fit the model` at you. catch 22.